# slack использование event api

Tags: java, slack

Не могу разобраться где взять "Request URL" для ивента, в задаче надо поприветствовать нового участника канала. И похоже для этого,
нужно подписать бота на:"member_joined_channel".

Comment: https://slack.com/api/ вот базовый url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно зарегистрировать новое приложение в самом slack. 
После регистрации у Вас появятся **App Credentials**, там все нужное для дальнейшей работы.  
Вам нужно подписаться на Event `team_join` либо `member_joined_channel`
Когда вы получаете уведомление, то можете отправить сообщение через [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)

вот пример webhook url-a `https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

пример отправки сообщения в чат

```
curl -X POST -H 'Authorization: Bearer xoxb-1234-56789abcdefghijklmnop' \
-H 'Content-type: application/json' \
--data '{"channel":"C061EG9SL","text":"I hope the tour went well, Mr. Wonka.","attachments": [{"text":"Who wins the lifetime supply of chocolate?","fallback":"You could be telling the computer exactly what it can do with a lifetime supply of chocolate.","color":"#3AA3E3","attachment_type":"default","callback_id":"select_simple_1234","actions":[{"name":"winners_list","text":"Who should win?","type":"select","data_source":"users"}]}]}' \
https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage
```

полезные ссылки 
[Generating Incoming Webhook URLs programmatically](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks#incoming_webhooks_programmatic)
[Sending messages using Incoming Webhooks](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks#getting-started)

Comment: Для того чтобы :"на Event team_join либо member_joined_channel" нужна какая то ссылка webhook url он не принимает

Comment: попробуйте создать новый webhook и там же будет ссылка на этот вэбхук https://kb.itglue.com/hc/en-us/articles/228469048-Setting-up-Slack-webhook-notifications